# Returning an unmodifiable map

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, unmodifiable

Using [`Collections.unmodifiableMap(...)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap%28java.util.Map%29), I'm trying to return an unmodifiable view of a map. Let's say I have the following method,

```
public final Map<Foo, Bar> getMap(){
    ...
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
}
```

Why is it legal elsewhere to do the following,

```
Map<Foo, Bar> map = getMap();
map.put(...);
```

This doesn't throw an [`UnsupportedOperationException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html) like I thought it would. Can someone please explain this, or suggest how I can successfully return a truly unmodifiable map?

Comment: Can you post more code?  It's hard to believe...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Are you sure you're not masking your exceptions somehow? This works absolutely fine, in that it throws `UnsupportedOperationException`:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> map = getMap();
        map.put("a", "b");
    }

    public static final Map<String, String> getMap(){
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("x", "y");
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
    }
}
```

I suggest you print out `map.getClass()` on the return value of the method - I would *expect* it to be an `UnmodifiableMap`.

Comment: @Jon, I wasn't aware that `UnsupportedOperationException` was a run-time error. I had assumed that it was a compile-time error. This is my fault, but your answer helped me realize how silly this question really was. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I created a small test program and my program threw an 'UnsupportedOperationException' when I tried to put data in.

code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class TestUnmodifiableMap
{
    Map<Integer, String> myMap;

    public TestUnmodifiableMap()
    {
        myMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    }

    public final Map<Integer, String> getMap()
    {
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(myMap);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TestUnmodifiableMap t = new TestUnmodifiableMap();
        Map<Integer, String> testMap = t.getMap();

        testMap.put(new Integer("1"), "Hello");
    }
}
```

What else are you doing in your class?

Answer (score 3):

There must be something else wrong. There's no way you can `put` something in that map after you wrapped it as an unmodifiable map.

I would also suggest to return

```
return Collections.<Foo, Bar>unmodifiableMap(map);
```

otherwise you will get "unchecked" warnings when compiling your code with -Xlint:unchecked.